# Unable to serialize Javascript object with JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have an object that looks like this when I do console.log()

```
0:
faceLandarks: [{...},...]
image: canvas
leftHandLandmarks: [{...},...]
```

There's more, but you get the idea.
When I try to serialize the object with JSON.stringify() the image type (canvas) is lost. I need a way to keep all the data in the object when I serialize it without having to import a library through npm  or similar.

I can add more Javascript files, but cannot use npm.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` doesn't preserve functions or custom classes. If you have a complex case you should pass a replacer/reviver to your `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` calls. See [JSON.stringify: Description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) for details.